# Как в Express.js использовать глобальную переменную User на всех страницах?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, веб-сервер, express

создаю, учебных целей ради, процесс регистрации и авторизации, на Next.js, React, Express. Возникла задача отображать логин пользователя на всех страницах сайта, знаю, что используя препроцессор, например, EJS, можно написать в файле app.js так

```
res.render('index', {
    user: {
      id,
      login
    }
  });
});
```

и затем в шаблоне просто обратиться к переменной

```
<%= user.login %>
```

Но как это сделать без EJS ?
У Next.js свой метод работы с експрессом, они предлагают готовый код

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
 })
```

Собственно, вопрос, как передать данные переменной user в данной ситуации ? Чтобы я мог достать юзера затем на странице реакт компонента.

Answer (score 0):

Положить какой-то идентификатор в req. Например:

```
http://some.ru/?id:userID
```

но это не очень удобно, поэтому рекомендую вам посмотреть в сторону работы с [сессиями](https://github.com/expressjs/session) или вытаскивать эти данные из куки.